# Vorperian - Fast analytical techniques problem 2.1d

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am working my way through Vorperian's book Fast analytical techniques for electrical and electronic circuits, and I've run into some trouble on problem 2.1d...

There is a sub-sub question that reads "Is there any significance to the feedback block g_x/g_o ?"

But there doesn't seem to be any reference to g_o (an admittance). There is a g_x/g_a block and a g_x/y_b block, but I can't find anything that g_o obviously refers to, unless it refers to the output admittance... but that would be kind of out of left field.

Hopefully someone has this book or has worked with it. You can see the question here, if it's not locked out or something:
http://books.google.com/books?id=DYgS4nkJ5W8C&lpg=PA56&dq=%22is%20there%20any%20significance%20to%20the%20feedback%20block%22&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=%22is%20there%20any%20significance%20to%20the%20feedback%20block%22&f=false

There doesn't seem to be an errata available, so I'm giving this a shot before emailing (bothering) the author...

Thanks!

Block diagram, copied from Google Books:
[image]

To clarify, the thing that's bugging me is that g_x / g_a doesn't seem to be significant. And maybe that's the answer to the question, but it's horribly confusing. Asked here in the hope that someone's taken a class using this book at some point, and possibly already struggled with this problem.

Comment: Id bother the author. I can't see the diagram you refer to so maybe you should copy it to your question or talk to the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like an obvious typo. Figure 2.34(f) does contain a feedback block g_x/g_a, and I'm pretty sure that's what's being referenced.

Comment: Understood, but that doesn't make sense to me in context of the book's question. I added a clarification to the bottom of my post.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

You are right. It is a typo and must be gx/ga. I appreciate your comments very much.

Take care,
Vatche